# stty on old AT&T unix: how to add End-key for "end of line"?

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, stty

How I can use the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> keyboard combination in emacs mode to go to the end of the line, but also be able to use the <kbd>End</kbd> key to do the same? How do I set that with stty?
I have tried this combination copied from linux terminal:

```
stty eol M-^?
```

but when I press <kbd>End</kbd> I get `F` on keyboard.

The system is old ATT System V on minicom terminal.
My term is 386AT and this is terminfo definition

```
#       Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/share/lib/terminfo/3/386AT
AT386|at386|386AT|386at|at/386 console @(#)386.ti 1.4,
        am, bw, eo, xon,
        colors#8, cols#80, lines#25, ncv#3, pairs#64,
        acsc=``aaffggjYk?lZm@nEooppqDrrsstCu4vAwBx3yyzz{{||}}~~,
        bel=^G, blink=\E[5m, bold=\E[1m, clear=\E[2J\E[H,
        cr=\r, cub=\E[%p1%dD, cub1=\E[D, cud=\E[%p1%dB,
        cud1=\E[B, cuf=\E[%p1%dC, cuf1=\E[C,
        cup=\E[%i%p1%02d;%p2%02dH, cuu=\E[%p1%dA, cuu1=\E[A,
        dch=\E[%p1%dP, dch1=\E[P, dl=\E[%p1%dM, dl1=\E[1M,
        ed=\E[J, el=\E[K, flash=^G, home=\E[H, ht=\t,                                                                   
        ich=\E[%p1%d@, ich1=\E[1@, il=\E[%p1%dL, il1=\E[1L,                                                             
        ind=\E[S, indn=\E[%p1%dS, invis=\E[9m, is2=\E[0;10m,                                                            
        kbs=\b, kcbt=^], kclr=\E[2J, kcub1=\E[D, kcud1=\E[B,                                                            
        kcuf1=\E[C, kcuu1=\E[A, kdch1=\E[P, kend=\E[Y,                                                                  
        kf1=\EOP, kf10=\EOY, kf11=\EOZ, kf12=\EOA, kf2=\EOQ,                                                            
        kf3=\EOR, kf4=\EOS, kf5=\EOT, kf6=\EOU, kf7=\EOV,                                                               
        kf8=\EOW, kf9=\EOX, khome=\E[H, kich1=\E[@, knp=\E[U,                                                           
        kpp=\E[V, krmir=\E0, op=\E[0m,                                                                                  
        pfx=\EQ%p1%{1}%-%d'%p2%s', rev=\E[7m, rin=\E[S,                                                                 
        rmacs=\E[10m, rmso=\E[m, rmul=\E[m, setab=\E[4%p1%dm,                                                           
        setaf=\E[3%p1%dm,                                                                                               
        setb=\E[4%?%p1%{1}%=%t4%e%p1%{3}%=%t6%e%p1%{4}%=%t1%e%p1%{6}%=%t3%e%p1%d%;m,                                    
        setf=\E[3%?%p1%{1}%=%t4%e%p1%{3}%=%t6%e%p1%{4}%=%t1%e%p1%{6}%=%t3%e%p1%d%;m,                                    
        sgr=\E[10m\E[0%?%p1%p3%|%t;7%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p4%t;5%;%?%p6%t;1%;%?%p9%t;12%;%?%p7%t;9%;m,                        
        sgr0=\E[0;10m, smacs=\E[12m, smso=\E[7m, smul=\E[4m,
```

Comment: is the remote side using readline by any chance? an .inputrc of `"\e[4~": end-of-line` would do it, if so.

Comment: no readline,old unix of 80's

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That `eol` setting is not for the key that would take you to the end of some line-editing buffer, that's a setting of the tty line discipline.

It is for its very basic line editor, the one used when entering input for applications (like `cat`, `sed`) that don't have their own line editor. That editor doesn't have cursor positioning, the only *editing* it can do is via backspace (`stty erase`), Ctrl+W (`stty werase`) and Ctrl+U (`stty kill`) possibly more on some systems.

It is done in the tty device driver itself in the kernel, the applications (`cat`, `sed`...) don't see those characters.

The `eol` setting is only to tell that driver to recognise a different (additional) character from linefeed (aka newline aka `^J`) as the line ending character. Upon entering that character, the line discipline would send the characters entered so far to the reading application.

For instance, to input text one word at a time instead of one line at a time, you could do:

```
stty eol ' '; cat
```

And you'd see that each time you press space, `cat` would output the text you've entered (including that space character).

If you're at the prompt of a command that implements its own line editor, then making <kbd>End</kbd> move the cursor to the end of the current buffer would not be done via `stty` but by specific configuration of that command (if at all).

For instance, with the `zsh` shell, that would be done with:

```
bindkey '^[[F' end-of-line
bindkey '^[OF' end-of-line
```

Assuming your terminal sends the `<ESC>[F` or `<ESC>OF` character sequence when you press that <kbd>End</kbd> key as your "F" suggests.

Some application will automatically bind <kbd>End</kbd> to their _end-of_line_ action. To do that, they will query the local termcap or terminfo terminal databases to find out what character sequence your terminal sends upon that key press.

For that, they use the `$TERM` variable. If the entry for that  key in that database does not match what your terminal sends, then that won't work.

You can try:

```
tput kend | sed -n l
```

To see what the database things the <kbd>End</kbd> key sends if your tput uses terminfo or check for your $TERM entry in /etc/termcap if using termcap. You may be able to find an entry there that more closely matches your minicom (or the terminal emulator that hosts it) behaviour.

### Edit based on new info

So, most likely, you're running `minicom` in a modern `xterm`-like terminal and communicating over serial. At the other end of the serial line, `getty` assumes you're running an at386 console (which I believe is actually the internal console driver of old PC-based AT&T systems). That is very far from a modern xterm.

Looking at a Solaris system here which in many respects is about as modern as your old AT&T system, there is a `xterm` entry in terminfo but it lacks the `kend` capability.

What you could do is upload the terminfo definition of your terminal on the machine you run minicom on (`infocmp > file`), transfer that to the SysV machine, and try and compile it over there with `tic` (and set `$TERM` to the same value of there, set the `TERMINFO` environment variable beforehand to something like `~/.terminfo` if you're not administrator there). If that doesn't work because the curses version is too ancient, you could use the vt100 entry of the AT&T system instead, and just edit in the `kend=\EOF` of your terminal, change the name and use `tic` again.

Like:

```
cat > my-term.info << \EOF
my-term|My VT100 compatible terminal with an end-key,
    am, mir, msgr, xenl, xon,
    cols#80, it#8, lines#24, vt#3,
    acsc=``aaffggjjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~,
    bel=^G, blink=\E[5m$<2>, bold=\E[1m$<2>,
    clear=\E[H\E[J$<50>, cr=\r, csr=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr,
    cub=\E[%p1%dD, cub1=\b, cud=\E[%p1%dB, cud1=\n,
    cuf=\E[%p1%dC, cuf1=\E[C$<2>,
    cup=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH$<5>, cuu=\E[%p1%dA,
    cuu1=\E[A$<2>, ed=\E[J$<50>, el=\E[K$<3>,
    el1=\E[1K$<3>, enacs=\E(B\E)0, home=\E[H, ht=\t,
    hts=\EH, ind=\n, ka1=\EOq, ka3=\EOs, kb2=\EOr, kbs=\b,
    kc1=\EOp, kc3=\EOn, kcub1=\EOD, kcud1=\EOB,
    kcuf1=\EOC, kcuu1=\EOA, kent=\EOM, kf0=\EOy, kf1=\EOP,
    kf10=\EOx, kf2=\EOQ, kf3=\EOR, kf4=\EOS, kf5=\EOt,
    kf6=\EOu, kf7=\EOv, kf8=\EOl, kf9=\EOw, rc=\E8,
    rev=\E[7m$<2>, ri=\EM$<5>, rmacs=^O, rmkx=\E[?1l\E>,
    rmso=\E[m$<2>, rmul=\E[m$<2>,
    rs2=\E>\E[?3l\E[?4l\E[?5l\E[?7h\E[?8h, sc=\E7,
    sgr=\E[0%?%p1%p6%|%t;1%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p1%p3%|%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;m%?%p9%t^N%e^O%;,
    sgr0=\E[m^O$<2>, smacs=^N, smkx=\E[?1h\E=,
    smso=\E[1;7m$<2>, smul=\E[4m$<2>, tbc=\E[3g, kend=\EOF
EOF
TERMINFO="$HOME/.terminfo" export TERMINFO
mkdir -p "$TERMINFO"
tic my-term.info
```

And add:

```
if [ "`tty`" = "the-serial-device" ] && [ "$TERM" = at386 ]; then
  TERMINFO=$HOME/.terminfo
  TERM=my-term
  export TERM TERMINFO
fi
```

to your `~/.profile` (where `the-serial-device` is whatever `tty` outputs when you login over serial.

Comment: Line disciplines have been in use before the late 1980s. Since the POSIX tty mode system was introduced around 1987, line disciplines are no longer used.

Comment: none of those solution works anyway thanks for answer

Comment: @elbarna, there's no solution in there, only explanations, if you tell us what application you're trying to make the End key work with and what you use for $TERM and what the terminfo or termcap entry looks like for that value, we may be able to give a solution.

Comment: Hi,i edit the question with new infos,thanks

Comment: @schily. Of course it does. It may be implemented as a STREAMS module now, but the line discipline is still there. (see `ldterm` in the output of `strconf` on Solaris for instance, run `strchg -pu ptem` in a terminal emulator or over ssh to see the effect of removing it).

Comment: `ldterm` is not a line discipline but **the** POSIX tty driver.

Comment: @schily, also known as the tty/terminal line discipline. What do you think `ld` stands for? Like on most other systems, I would expect Solaris would be able to push a different line discipline onto serial or pty devices like a SLIP line discipline for instance. Feel free to call it something else if you want but please let me or the man page call it the tty line discipline.

Comment: The term linediscipline was introduced by BSD around 1980 to permit to switch the behavior of the tty driver into a mode that supports job control from `csh`. This is based on the ioctl `TIOCSETD` using the value `NTTYDISC`. On Solaris, there is no support for this switching. You will get an error if you try to set the "new" linedisc".

Comment: @schily, whether it's done with a TIOCSETD ioctl or with a STREAMS push, or whether it's in STREAMS module, hardcoded within a particular line-like device or not or whether it's on Linux, BSD or SysV is irrelevant. The term "tty line discipline" nowadays refers to the "terminal handling" behaviour (including the line editor, and job control handling) that can be added on top of a line device like a serial or pty device.

Comment: I use the tic/infocmp solution but..doesn't work.

Comment: `ldterm` is a streams module and there exists no alternative streams module for tty handling. The term line discipline was only used when there was a need to switch to the "new discipline" for csh. If you still use it, you seem to live in the past.

Comment: @schily, so I suppose Solaris, Linux live in the past as that's what their manuals call it. And Linux at least can install a different line discipline on a serial device so it can be used for different things than ttys (like for mice or a SLIP/ppp interface)

Comment: Around 1983, AT&T really wrote a line discipline named `ldterm` that implemented the new AT&T method that has become the base for POSIX tty handling. Linux lives in that past.... SunOS-4.0 (1987) was the first OS that implemented streams and a stream based ldterm. SunOS did however keep the manual page from AT&T. Sometimes it helps to know history.